# Android instrumentation

Tags: android, instrumentation

How do I make a test project using instrumentation that tests an application from an Android device not from command line. I think I should add a dependency in the manifest.xml file but not sure how to do this.

Is there any good tutorial of doing this?

Thank in advance..

Comment: If you like to work with Eclipse look here: http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_eclipse.html Also check this project out for black box app testing: https://code.google.com/p/robotium/